# Python opening a file and putting list of names on separate lines

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a python program using Python 3

I have to open a text file and read a list of names, print the list, sort the list in alphabetical order and then finally re-print the list.
There's a little more to it than that BUT the problem I am having is that I'm supposed to print the list of names with each name on a separate line

Instead of printing each name on a separate line, it prints the list all on one line. 
How can I fix this?

```
    def main():

        #create control loop
        keep_going = 'y'

        #Open name file
        name_file = open('names.txt', 'r')

        names = name_file.readlines()

        name_file.close()

        #Open outfile
         outfile = open('sorted_names.txt', 'w')

        index = 0
        while index < len(names):
             names[index] = names[index].rstrip('\n')
             index += 1

        #sort names
        print('original order:', names)
        names.sort()
        print('sorted order:', names)

        #write names to outfile
        for item in names:
            outfile.write(item + '\n')
        #close outfile   
        outfile.close()

        #search names
        while keep_going == 'y' or keep_going == 'Y':

            search = input('Enter a name to search: ')

            if search in names:
                print(search, 'was found in the list.')
                keep_going = input('Would you like to do another search Y for yes: ')
            else:
                print(search, 'was not found.')

                keep_going = input('Would you like to do another search Y for yes: ')



    main()
```

Comment: my bad sorry. I'm using Wing IDE 101 4.1 I screwed that one up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `print('original order:', names)`. This is printing all the list in a single line. So do print each element of the list in a new line, you have to do something like:

```
print('original order:')
for name in names:
    print(name)
names.sort()
print('sorted order:')
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: @julio: `print` is a FUNCTION in Python 3. Please consider editing your answer, including deleting 'pythonic'. If print being a statement was considered 'pythonic', it would not have been changed.

Comment: @John, you were right, I was thinking in Python 2.*, **but**, just so you know, Python 3.* is not a correction of Python 2.*, is just another _branch_, so I actually keep thinking that `print` as a statement is more 'pythonic'.